# Internal Geneva drive calulations/design

Tags: gears

So there is a lot of information out there about designing an external Geneva drive, but I can't seem to find anything about designing an internal one. I'm trying to design something similar to this (but with a different number of positions):

[image: Internal Geneva Drive]

I know the internal drive is based off a calculations from a triangle, and I'd assume the the internal one is too, but it's just not clicking for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Try https://ecommons.cornell.edu/handle/1813/57662 -- search on "mechanisms for intermittent motion" if it doesn't come up with a book of that title.

Comment: I just saw this now and skimmed through Chapter 9 on Geneva Mechanism. This is a tone of information and exactly what I was trying to find. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i finally stumbled upon something last night that had had some good tables and figures. See the link below

[Kinematics Characteristics of The Internal & External Geneva
Mechanism Under The Effect of Multi Design Parameters](http://uotechnology.edu.iq/tec_magaz/2016/volum342016/No.09.A.2016/[11Text.pdf)

Specifically it had this image which helped to visualize things better. Turns out it is using the same triangle that the external gear uses for figuring out the center point of the driver and driven gears.

[image]